How can I completely uninstall KDE after installing with sudo apt install kde-full? from ubuntu 24.04
I recently installed KDE on my system using the command sudo apt install kde-full, but I now want to completely uninstall it. I would appreciate guidance on how to remove all KDE packages and dependencies.

Have you tried apt purge --autoremove kde-full  which is the reverse off what you said you did... Do note some changes (eg. KDE Plymouth wallpapers) may have been installed as part of the installation scripts when those packages installed; those will NOT be removed when you uninstall packages as placed on your system via script & not package itself, but just select the plymouth wallpaper you prefer if you don't want to see Kubuntu/KDE)

Have you tried
apt purge --autoremove kde-full

which is the reverse of what you said you did (ie. reverses sudo apt install kde-full).
Do note some changes (eg. KDE Plymouth wallpapers) may have been installed as part of the installation scripts when those packages installed; those will NOT be removed when you uninstall packages as placed on your system via script & not the package itself (directly anyway), but just select the plymouth wallpaper you prefer if you don't want to see Kubuntu/KDE.

You can try this
Start in text-only mode
Switch on your computer. Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, and press and hold Shift, which will bring up the Grub menu.
Select the line which starts with Advanced options.
Select the line ending with (recovery mode)
Press Return and your machine will begin the boot process.
After a few moments, your PC should display a menu with a number of options, including Drop to root shell prompt. Press Return with this option highlighted.
The PC will start in a terminal.

Run these commands:
Mount partitions in read-write mode
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all

Update repositories
apt update

Install aptitude and deborphan
apt install --reinstall aptitude deborphan

Eliminate kde
apt remove kde-plasma-desktop

Eliminate the components of kde that are not necessary in Ubuntu
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(kde),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'

Reinstall Ubuntu-desktop
apt install --reinstall Ubuntu-desktop

Eliminate orphan packages
deborphan
apt --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)

Remove unnecessary packages
apt autoremove

Remove downloaded packages
apt clean

Restart system
reboot

